# How to secure a local SVN repository using EFS on my desktop?

Tags: svn, encryption

I am using a local svn repo on my desktop. When i manually enabled EFS on the repository folder SVN could not access it. However i would like the repository to be encrypted when i am not logged in. Any ideas and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like an EFS configuration issue, which is not on topic on stackoverflow. Development environment questions are on-topic, but this is unlikely to be directly related to SVN, which just needs an accessible file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i faced a similar issue i used vbscript to encrypt the folder during log off and decrypt it during log on. If you are using windows, you could use the following vbscript's. Create both the scripts in two separate files.

```
'Encrypt.vbs
Dim strDir, objShell, FSO, WshShell
strDir = "D:\Repositories"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
retval = WshShell.Run("CIPHER /E /S:" & strDir, 0, True)
MsgBox("Success")

'Decrypt.vbs
Dim strDir, objShell, FSO, WshShell
strDir = "D:\Repositories"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
retval = WshShell.Run("CIPHER /D /S:" & strDir, 0, True)    
MsgBox("Success")
```

1. Execute the Run command "gpedit.msc"
2. On left pane select Local Computer Policy | User Configuration | Windows Settings | Scripts(Logon/Logoff)
3. On the right pane double-click on "logon"
4. On log on properties dialog click "Show Files..." button
5. The location "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logon" opens up
6. Copy Decrypt.vbs to this location
7. Similarly copy Encrypt.vbs to "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff"
8. On Logon Properties dialog, click Add button and select Decrypt.vbs
9. Similarly on Logoff Properties dialog, click Add button and select Encrypt.vbs
10. Execute the Run command  "gpupdate" and wait for the policy to be updated
11. Log-off and log in as another user and verify that the Repositories folder is encrypted by trying to read any human readable file, say readme.txt.
12. Now every time you log in the repository is decrypted and accessible to SVN and when you log off the repo remains encrypted on the disk.